# React App on Heroku getting Invalid Host Header

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, react-router-dom

Deployed my React App onto Heroku and opened my app to get an Invalid Host Header.

Anyone have any ideas what else might be causing this? I keep looking back at past projects to see if I have anything setup differently, but so far can't figure it out.

I tried every solution I could find online, and the only one that got the page to load was to remove my "proxy": "http://localhost:8080" from my package.json but the app can't use the back-end.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
console.log('loading dev environments');
require('dotenv').config();
```

}

```
require('dotenv').config();

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
const path = require('path');
console.log('YOU ARE IN THE PRODUCTION ENV');
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../build/static')));
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../build/'));
});
```

}

Figured it has to do with not switching to a production configuration but I have my files setup the same way as past projects and have the code for my node server to change for production too.

Comment: same issue, and no answer..